# Wordpress search query with attributes

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom search form that populates with product attributes. The url generated is something like `?s=&post_type=product&pa_accreditation=19&pa_course-type=21&pa_date=9&pa_location=24`, however, this returns all products and the attributes in the string are ignored.

How to add attributes to the search string.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp/add_query_var/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a similar question to this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69271/search-url-parameters-query

Maybe your variables "pa_accreditation", "pa_course" and "pa_date" are not defined in your query_vars

As mentioned in the link above, you can do this like so

```
function new_query_var() {
  global $wp;
  $wp->add_query_var('country');
}

add_filter('init', 'new_query_var');
```